# Custom CALayer wont respond to selector

Tags: ios, calayer

I need a custom layer (extended by new variable and a method) and did it like below.
The problem is that the layer won't respond to my method:

> -[CALayer drawHourCircleWithDayLightStart:dayLightEnd:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a6d560**

It seems like my custom layer is not treated as HourCircleLayer but as CALayer.
But do I have to change here?

My implementation looks like this:

```
@interface HourCircleLayer : CALayer
   @property (strong) UIColor *dayColor;   // default yellowColor
   @property (strong) UIColor *nightColor; // default blueColor
   + (id)layer;
   - (void)drawHourCircleWithDayLightStart:(NSDate *)startDate dayLightEnd:(NSDate *)endDate animated:(BOOL)animated;
@end

@implementation HourCircleLayer
  + (id)layer
  {
     id layer = [CALayer layer];
     [layer setValue:[UIColor yellowColor] forKey:kDayPortionColorKey];
     [layer setValue:[UIColor blueColor]   forKey:kNightPortionColorKey];

     return layer;
  }

  - (void)drawHourCircleWithDayLightStart:(NSDate *)startDate dayLightEnd:(NSDate *)endDate animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
     self.withAnimation = animated;
     [self setDayLightStart:[self hourAngleForDate:startDate]];
     [self setDayLightEnd:[self hourAngleForDate:endDate]];
  }

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you initialize `CALayer`, but not your `HourCircleLayer`. In your  `+ (id)layer` method change:

```
id layer = [CALayer layer];
```

to

```
HourCircleLayer layer = [[HourCircleLayer alloc] init];
...

return [layer autorelease]; //Use autorelease if not using ARC
```

Comment: Yes, I did that already. Siam brought me on the right path. Just without autorelease as I use ARC.

Answer (score 1):

the second method is not a class method, so you should do like this

```
HourCircleLayer *hourCircleLayer = [[HourCircleLayer alloc] init];
[hourCircleLayer drawHourCircleWithDayLightStart:dayLightEnd:animated:];
```

Comment: works - thanks a lot. It brought me also onto the track to do it with  +(id)layer.